# Create polygon geometry from BBOX coordinates in PostGIS

Tags: sql, geometry, polygon, postgis

I have a table `mytable` with coordinates representing Bounding BOX of an object as a text string in column `geom_bbox` like `"548477,6591107,548493,6591121"`. Coordinates in EPSG3301 in meters. I want to create a polygon geometry, a rectangle geometry using those coordinates. 
More example coordinates:

```
"548477,6591107,548493,6591121"
"545827,6587929,545864,6588021"
"539646,6586576,539694,6586621"
"549054,6594762,549101,6594811"
"547131,6589014,547182,6589046"
"547131,6589014,547182,6589046"
```

Is it possible with PostGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only bounding boxes, use the function [ST_MakeEnvelope](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html). This function creates a rectangle from 4 coordinates (2 points). First split the text with [string_to_array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) and the than use the result as coordinates:

```
SELECT ST_MakeEnvelope(arr[1]::double precision,
                       arr[2]::double precision,
                       arr[3]::double precision,
                       arr[4]::double precision, 
                       3301) 
FROM (SELECT string_to_array(geom_bbox,',') AS arr FROM mytable) as foo;
```